# Why do I have to cast results from dynamic coming into typed parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I have a simple dynamic object that returns a double:

```
class MyDynamic : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = 2.0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, I try to call a method that takes an int:

```
    private static void SomeMethod(int number)
    {

    }
```

Then, I make a call and pass my value from the `dynamic` into the method:

```
        dynamic x = new MyDynamic();
        SomeMethod(x.number);
```

Now, this causes an exception because the runtime complains it can't find a relevant method. Is that the expected behavior? I would have expected the runtime to automatically cast the returned value to whatever the type requested by the method is (int, in this instance).

Is this how stuff is supposed to work?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit the question to provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, rather than just snippets - and show the full exception in your question too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would have expected the runtime to automatically cast the returned value to whatever the type requested by the method is (int, in this instance).

Why would you expect it to do that? There's no implicit conversion from `double` to `int` normally, so why would you expect it in a dynamically-typed context?

To put it another way - if `x.number` were *statically* typed to return `double`, you'd get a compile-time failure. The execution-time failure when using dynamic typing is mirroring the same failure. Basically, the attempt to find the right method to call is being deferred until execution time, when the type of the argument is known. The type of the argument turns out to be `double`, and there's no implicit conversion from `double` to `int`, so you're getting an exception.

If you try it the other way round - supplying an `int` in `TryGetMember` and then calling a method accepting `double` - *then* the implicit conversion should kick in.

Note that you can use the explicit conversion from `double` to `int` with a cast:

```
SomeMethod((int) x.number);
```

That forces overload resolution at compile-time, and just the conversion of `x.number` to `int` at execution time... which is fine here because the *explicit* conversion from `double` to `int` exists.

Note that you don't have to use a method to demonstrate this:

```
int y = x.number; // Fails at execution time
int z = (int) x.number; // Works
```

Basically, the conversion from `double` to `int` is explicit, and that requirement for you to be explicit is upheld in dynamic typing too.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I was over-expecting dynamic to behave more like dynamic languages (where you would expect this conversion to occur automatically). Because at the end of the day, the DLR bits of `dynamic` need to interact with the strictly typed C# code, this makes total sense. Thanks.

Comment: @ShaharPrish - even in dynamic languages, they don't just allow willy-nilly conversion of types that can result in data loss without throwing some kind of error (at least not in any decent dynamic language).  What exactly would you expect?  That it just truncate the decimal and not tell you about it?  That's a huge and potentially catastrophic error waiting to happen.

Comment: Well.. Quite a few dynamic languages do allow for this (although your "Decent" bit will allow you to discount all of them). JavaScript when talking to COM objects (which is of course not the language itself, but the extensions built into it to allow the communication) will just do this transparently. Same with vbscript. Same with VB/VBA. Same with most flavors or SQL which are a sort of a scripting language. Other common dynamic languages/scripts do not have a definition for ints vs. doubles and so it's hard to find relevant examples.